# display the price without discount in the subtotal cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want when the product has a discount, in the cart, in the subtotal instead of showing the price with the discount, it will show the price without the discount, see the picture below and you will understand :
[image]

i use the following hook, when 1 product is in the cart, it displays correctly, but when a product with a price of $20 is added to the cart, instead of the sum of 2 products, the price of the second product, which is $20, is displayed in subtotal to give

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal( $subtotal, $compound, $cart ) {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal = wc_price( $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price() * $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    return $subtotal;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 10, 3 );
```

thank you for your time and answering my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal( $subtotal, $compound, $cart ) {
    $subtotal = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price() * $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    $subtotal = wc_price ( $subtotal ); 
    return $subtotal;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're always overwriting your $subtotal instead of adding to it

```
function filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal( $subtotal, $compound, $cart ) {
    $subtotal = 0;
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $cart_item ) {
            $subtotal += intval(wc_price( $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price() * $cart_item['quantity'] ));
                 // ^^^^^^^^^ change is here
        }
    return $subtotal;
} add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: $subtotal += wc_price( $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price() * $cart_item['quantity'] ); expects to add a numeric value. if you get a string at this point, you might have to parse it into a int like so: $subtotal += parseInt(wc_price( $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price() * $cart_item['quantity'] ));

Comment: this happens because you overwrite the value of the variable $subtotal every time your forach loops thru another cart item. when you use $subtotal = something. in my answer i suggest using $subtotal += something in order to add the new value to $subtotal

Comment: i edited my answer, in my comment i used the js intparser, but you need to parse your return to an int using php syntax. try parsing what you get from wc_price to an int